# Ubuntu one sign in error (after installation completed): "nonetype" object has no attribute "make file"

Tags: ubuntu-one

I received this error message when trying to sign in using Ubuntu One (for Windows). I'm using Windows 7 and just installed Ubuntu One for Windows. Already created an account.

"nonetype" object has no attribute "make file"

Answer (score 1):

The logs of the application are located in :

C:\Users\$your_user\AppData\Local\xdg

Please can you go to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client and a a bug report stating what was the issue. We did have some server issues when we launched the app so it might be that the problem you have.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run Ubuntu with Administrator privileges (right mouse click on icon - run as admin)?

Comment: Didn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu One help
Ubuntu One helpFAQsWhy do I get a 'NoneType' object has not attribute 'makefile' when setting up my computer with Ubuntu One?
This error will normally occur when you are behind a proxy server and try to setup Ubuntu One. You'll likely see the error after completing step 3 of the setup process. Ubuntu One does not currently work behind a proxy server.

https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/why-do-i-get-a-nonetype-object-has-not-attribute-makefile-when-setting-up-my-computer-with-ubuntu-one/